# Algorithmic solultion for eigenproblem over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algorithms, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i am looking for the standard algorithms for solving eigenvalue problems over finite fields. (For example the algorithm implemented in GAP).
I googled a lot but did not come to a conclusion.
I saw Berlekamps algorithm and a few derivates to factor the characteristic polynomial into irreducible factors and obtain the eigenvalues this way. Assuming the characteristic polynomial splits into $n$ irreducible factors, the
complexity of Berlekamp´s algorithm is $\mathcal O (pn^3)$, where $p$ is the size of the field and $n$ the rank of the matrix.

> So my question is: Do i have to run the Gauß-algorithm for every
>   eigenvalue which makes a total cost of $\mathcal O (n n^3) = \mathcal
>  O (n^4)$?

So it would be slower than over fields with characteristic 0, which i doubt. I have read that solving eigenvalue problems over finite fields is easier and exact (no floating points, no rounding errors). Because of the special structure of my matrix 
you can **assume that the eigenvalues are field elements.**

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what method MAGMA uses by default for finite fields, but it looks like the [Hessenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Hessenberg_and_Tri-diagonal_matrices) algorithm.  It seems like once the matrix is reduced to this form, it is easy to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors, and the eigenvectors can be transformed back to eigenvectors of $A$ with the saved similarity matrix. It has a few options though as mentioned [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/258#2406).

Comment: isn´t this givens-rotation and householder transformation floating point stuff? And finite field computation is exact?

Comment: I'm not sure if the same method is used to put the matrix into Hessenberg form, it looks like the new book by Mullen and Panario has some details https://books.google.it/books?id=YADSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA529&lpg=PA529&dq=finite+fields+%22hessenberg+form%22&source=bl&ots=HpmxCwZNBB&sig=4AD1B13vhTsPbl7M0mdwQkV6sIM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBWoVChMItav4oeWyxwIVQRQsCh12ZgUs#v=onepage&q=finite%20fields%20%22hessenberg%20form%22&f=false